# Strange rendering of question title

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, title

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704536/replicate-and) which appears to have an incredibly strange title:

[image]

In reality, however, the title is `replicate and ...`, where `replicate` and `...` are a function name and special character in [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r). While we probably could change this title to `replicate and dot-dot-dot`, this seems to be some kind of error in the rendering of titles. Can it be corrected?

Comment: How about [this question title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838807/unable-to-extract-dic)? How do we fix it?

Comment: @DavidArenburg: https://youtu.be/rYJVo9v6MNI?t=5m13s

Comment: "I just came across this question which appears to have an incredibly strange title" write a better one?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I folllowed the link and got to a cut-off from "Friends" where Gunther asks Phoebie's data to "*put the mouse back in the house*". However, I'm missing the (guessingly witty) relation to this question. Please explain.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: You know that explaining jokes kills a kitten somewhere, right? Do you get why David's link is funny? Now that you see why the title is funny, Gunther asks to put that mouse back in the house. But you can't unsee it, can you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, when you **pronounce** the title, I see it. (Or rather - I **hear** it.) This was a bit far-fetched in my opinion. Or it might be that I "see" in my head "deee ayyy seee" and not "dick". But I get the joke now and I'm sure that you didn't have to explain it too explicitly so the kitten might be bruised but [will probably make it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeCyyhmHICU).   :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a "feature", see [Stop rewriting trailing exclamation marks as question marks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115327/stop-rewriting-trailing-exclamation-marks-as-question-marks)

> Multiple . collapsed into one

Combined with other title processing rules this drops the ellipsis from the end of a title altogether.

I've edited the title and inverted the sentence to avoid this:

[Using "..." and "replicate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704536/and-replicate)

As long as the ellipsis is not the last 'word' in the title it is preserved.

Comment: Makes sense, though I would have expected the title to appear as `replicate and .` according to that rule.

Comment: @Thomas: I think it is the space in between.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so... status-by-design?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: yeah, I fear so.